# Fragmentación de una base de datos en 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estaba trabajando con una base de datos para sucursales y ahora resulta que necesito hacer una partición horizontal de forma en la que cada sucursal tenga su propia base de datos. Para esto podría hacer un copy paste con diferentes nombres para cada sucursal, pero esto no me parece conveniente ya que el código se extendería repitiendo lo mismo una y otra vez. Existe alguna forma de realizar esto por medio de un código en un query sin necesidad de copiar la creación de las mismas tablas pero en diferentes bases? Además existe una forma de consultar los datos de todas sin necesidad de un "union"? Un ejemplo de esto que no deseo realizar:

```
CREATE DATABASE Sucursal1
CREATE TABLE Sucursal1.dbo.Sucursal(
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    numero int not null,
    idTaller int not null,
    ubicacion geography not null,
    ubicacion3 as ubicacion.STAsText()
)


CREATE DATABASE Sucursal2
CREATE TABLE Sucursal2.dbo.Sucursal(
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    numero int not null,
    idTaller int not null,
    ubicacion geography not null,
    ubicacion3 as ubicacion.STAsText()
)

CREATE PROCEDURE Sucursal1.dbo.BuscarSucursal
AS
    SELECT numero, idTaller
    FROM Sucursal1.dbo.Sucursal
    UNION
    SELECT numero, idTaller
    FROM Sucursal2.dbo.Sucursal
BEGIN
END
```

Agradezco su aporte :)

Comment: Por qué dices **tienes** que crear una base de datos para cada sucursal?

Comment: Si ya tienes cargada información, puede resultar más práctico hacer tres copias de la misma base de datos, con una secuencia de `backup/restore` y eliminar la información que no pertenece a cada una. De esta manera, tendrás exactamente la misma estructura en las 3 bases de datos. A partir de allí, si quieres mantener las estructuras idénticas, deberás ser bastante cuidadosa para incluir en tus scripts DDL toda la información (tal como nombres de constraints, por ejemplo) y asegurarte de correr cada script en las tres bases de datos.

Comment: Recomiendo cambiar el título de la pregunta. En el lingo de sql, **Fragmentación** es algo muy distinto a esto.

Answer (score 2):

Lo bello de SQLServer (y cualquier otro RBDMS) es que puedes hacer las cosas tan sencillas o tan complicadas como quieres. Este es un caso de este tipo. Hay dos respuestas: La ultra sencilla y la ultra complicada.

### Opción Ultra Sencilla

> Existe alguna forma de realizar esto por medio de un código en un query sin necesidad de copiar la creación de las mismas tablas pero en diferentes bases?

Si estás utilizando SSMS (SqlServer Management Studio) puedes dar click derecho a la **base de datos "madre"**, luego en **Tasks (tareas), Generate Scripts** y le das single file, para que los genere en un solo archivo. Esto te creará un script para cada uno de los objetos de la base de datos. Una vez hecho esto, sólo deberás darle buscar y reemplazar el nombre de la sucursal copiada por el de la sucursal nueva. Si lo hiciste bien, las tablas, SP's, Vistas, y demás objetos tendrán el nombre de la nueva sucursal. Es cuestión de darle F5 para correrlo y listo, tienes tu nueva bd para la nueva sucursal. Este [artículo de la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#script-a-database-by-using-the-generate-scripts-option) te puede ayudar mucho

> Además existe una forma de consultar los datos de todas sin necesidad de un "union"?

Para el asunto del `UNION`... No veo nada de malo tener un sp que te busque los datos de todas las sucursales y realizar un `Alter` a ese objeto cuando tengas una nueva. No es NADA complejo y además puedes hacer un simple Copy-Paste con el nombre de la nueva bd. Eso sí, ASEGÚRATE de filtrar con el `WHERE` en cada uno de los union. Si no, tendrás un `full table scan` en cada una de las tablas.

Personalmente, prefiero la solución sencilla. Agregar una nueva bd para una sucursal no debería tomar más de media hora con este procedimiento.

Pero si te gusta vivir al límite, sigue la

## Opción ULTRA - MEGA complicada

> Existe alguna forma de realizar esto por medio de un código en un query sin necesidad de copiar la creación de las mismas tablas pero en diferentes bases?

En pocas palabras, la forma ultra complicada comprende obtener las definiciones de los objetos por medio de una query a las tablas de sistema `sys.procedures, sys.tables, sys.objects` y un join con `sys.sql_modules`. Luego un query dinámico que reemplace el nombre de la bd original con el nuevo, iterando sobre cada uno de los resultados de las tablas de sistemas con un cursor.

Así obtendrás el mismo script que obtendrías con la opción ultra sencilla, pero de una manera larga y tortuosa.

> Además existe una forma de consultar los datos de todas sin necesidad de un "union"?

Sí. Igual a lo de arriba. Obtienes una lista de las bases de datos, mediante un query a la `master` y con un cursor iteras sobre ellas, armando un query dinámico para que agregue un union por cada una de las bd's.

### Conclusión

Este es uno de los casos en que podemos seguir el razonamiento de la [Navaja de Ockham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navaja_de_Ockham) (parafraseando):

> **La solución más sencilla suele ser, generalmente, la correcta**

No te compliques. Genera los scripts y le pegas el nuevo nombre. Saludos.